# hardhat & ehters v5 (5.7.0) I want to make sure that the contract is working normally

Tags: testing, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm going to test and distribute the contract through hardhat, but the latest version of the tool doesn't seem to support compatibility with v5. I want to proceed with it using the old version of the tool, but I'm having a hard time because I don't think there are many related documents. What should I do??

The version of ether in our project is 5.7.

I want to make sure that the contract is working normally.